# Using live() and liveQuery() jQuery 1.4.4

Tags: jquery

It seems jquery .live and liveQuery cannot coexist together...Is this true? The reason I am asking is I am migrating legacy code and was going to live liveQuery in place, but liveQuery doesn't seem to work in jquery 1.4.4. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: As far as i know, livequery should work fine in jQuery 1.4.4, however, most of it's functionality has been built directly into jQuery behind `.live()` and `.delegate()`. The only thing that didn't come over was running code when a particular element is added to the page which was inefficient anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post some code or further explain "doesn't seem to work".

This isn't my jsfiddle but it shows that liveQuery and jQuery 1.4.4 work together.

http://jsfiddle.net/x3tds/1/

Comment: Hmm it must be something else then, some of the liveQuery works some of it doesn't